# How to get the screen overlay to deactivate on an lgg stylo

Tags: settings

I would like to deactivate this overlay over the apps so i can better use my phone apps. Please give detailed instructions on how to disable

Answer (score 2):

When the popup appears which says "`Screen overlay detected`" just push the "`Open settings`" button and there disable all apps overlay permission.

If you don't get that popup follow theese steps:

- Open `Settings` (nut/gear icon).
- Scroll down to `Apps`.
- From within the `Apps` portion of settings, again choose the settings nut/gear icon.
- Choose `Draw over other apps`.
- *(Optional)* Click on the additional menu (3 dots), then choose `Show system` to get at **all** of the apps that are asking to draw over others, including system apps like `Phone Services`.

After this you shouldn't experience any issue with overlays.

Answer (score 1):

If that fails check: Settings, Accessibility, motor & cognition, and make sure the touch assistant and touch control areas are OFF.